# How do i select items in a gallery usign checkboxes

Tags: pdf, checkbox, gallery, powerapps, items

i'm having problems with a gallery in powerapps, i'm trying to select multiple items in the gallery using checkboxes, now i can select just one item from the gallery, i've tried a couple of things an nothing seems to work. I need to select more tahn one so i can print multiple items in PDF.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPUCH.png)

I tried with Updates, ForAll, Patch, both in on check and on select but nothing seems to work, everything keeps giving errors.

Comment: @K J sorry i didn't explain myself correctly, by printing i meant downloading the multiple pdf one after another, all this in powerapps.